# What's the best method to create a thread that can be ended from the main thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm capturing data from an accelerometer. I want the user to be able to begin recording data and stop recording by pressing a start and stop button respectively. I decided to do this with threads so the start button creates a thread that captures data and the stop button stops that thread and grabs the data that was recorded.

The problem that I'm having is that either no data is recorded or when the stop button is pressed, the thread doesn't end and instead keeps recording data for anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes.

What I'm doing right now is that the thread runs a loop that records the data and checks to see if a variable is set to True, if so the loop is supposed to end. I also have an end() function that is meant to be called from the main thread and is suppose to set the variable to True in order to end the thread.

```
class Capture(Thread):
def __init__(self,accel):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.accel=accel
    self.ended=False
    self.data=[]
    self.lock=Lock()

def run(self):
    while self.isEnded()==False:
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.data.append(self.accel.read())
        self.lock.release()

def getData(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    d=self.data
    self.data=[]
    self.lock.release()
    return d

def isEnded(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    end=self.ended
    self.lock.release()
    return end

def end(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.ended=True
    self.lock.release()
```

Comment: can `self.accel.read()` block for several minutes? Have you tried: `data = self.accel.read() \n with lock: self.data.append(data)` to avoid blocking `getData()` for long. Or read in a smaller chunks until a record separator? Or just use `Queue.get_nowait()` without the explicit lock. You don't need the lock around `self.ended`. If you need to wait for `isEnded()` in *another* thread; you could use `threading.Event.wait()`. You might not need a thread at all, to read from a file without blocking the GUI e.g., [`GObject.io_add_watch`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63)

Comment: self.accel.read() cannot block for several minutes, the timeout is set to one second. The problem isn't that getData() is blocked, but that when I call end(), the thread will either end immediately, but produce no data or continue running at its normal rate for another 5 seconds to several minutes. The block comes in the main thread when i call thread.end().

Comment: Have you tried the change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know python very well at all but I'll take a guess. If accel.read() calls out to some external code (eg a device driver) and blocks for a second then the python interpreter is also blocked. No other thread will run. When the read finally returns you release the lock. At this point the interpreter is going to have to decide what to do next, and your thread merely loops, takes the lock again and goes back to reading (and being blocked)

So I'm guessing that you're falling foul of interpreter lock, and that there's an element of blind luck involved in whether your main thread gets run at all, in which case your stop button handling doesn't happen.

Could that be it?